# Should I use Rails routing helpers inside RSpec tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, testing, rspec

On RSpec Request [doc page](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec) we can read that

> Request specs provide a thin wrapper around Rails' integration tests, and are
>   designed to drive behavior through the full stack, **including routing
>   (provided by Rails)** and without stubbing (that's up to you).

and in the provided code example we see `get "/widgets/new"`. However, we have access to all routes helper inside requests specs (like `new_widget_path`). I see that some projects use url helpers in specs, some not.

What is considered as best the practise? Can I use routing helpers inside integration (or / and ) feature tests? What consequences have each of these approaches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the routing helpers are available for both feature & request specs.

Explicitly writing the URL's for API routes for example does in some ways guarantee that they cannot deviate from the documented URL. But writing:

```
 GET "/api/v1/users/#{user.id}/something/#{something.id}"
```

Is not great for test readability. So it's a trade off.